# Approach to testing difference from a bivariate null distribution generated by randomization

Tags: autocorrelation, kernel-smoothing, bivariate, permutation-test

I would like to test if each of the red observations is more extreme in variable `xy[,2]` than 95% of a null hypothesis (black dots) generated by randomization.

I am not interested in relationships between the two variables.

My instinct is to bin `xy[,1]` and ask if a red observation that falls in a given bin is more extreme than 95% of the random points in that bin.

Can anyone suggest if this is an appropriate approach?  Could a bivariate kernel help here?

EDIT:  I should have noted that observations will be autocorrelated with respect to xy[,1].  The black points represent randomly generated tessellations of a surface, while the red points are observed tessellations.  xy[,1] is a descriptive measure of the tessellation, while xy[,2] describes the fit of a tessellation to a constant set of points.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "generated by randomization"? What is being randomized?

Comment: @guest  I had hoped to avoid too much detail, however, please see additional details added to question.